# Formatting help when user clicks on form text box

Tags: html, css

Newbie here, please be gentle. When the user clicks on a form text box (like Email or First name), the text box border changes to blue and the border is wider compared to its format at rest. I want to change it so that when the user clicks, the text box border does not change color and border width, but the text box background changes from the light gray (#fafafa) to white (#ffffff).

The email service provider wrote the original form code (they don't provide any support for customization), and I modified the formatting inline (e.g. text box size, font attributes, rounded corners, button formatting etc.) by researching HTML attributes online, and through trial and error.

```
<form id="IBNSubscribeForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="">
    <p>Email*<br/><input id="IBNSubscribeEmail" type="text/CSS" name="email" value="" placeholder="name@xyz.com" size="34" style="background-color:#fafafa; height:3em; border:1px solid #cccccc; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px "/><p/>
    <p>First name* <br> <input name="first_name" type="text" size="34" style="background-color:#fafafa; height:3em; border:1px solid #cccccc; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px" /><p/>
    <input id="IBNSubscribeButton" type="button" value="SUBSCRIBE!" style="font:Proxima Nova; font-size:13px; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; background-color: #faac44; width: 11em; height: 4em; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border:none">
    <span id="IBNStatusMessage"></span>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*([._+-])*([a-zA-Z0-9]))*@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+(.))+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/;
return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}
(function($) {
    $.fn.EmailCampaignsSubscribe = function(client_id, lists, opt){
var defaults = {
form: "IBNSubscribeForm",
email: "IBNSubscribeEmail",
            msg: "IBNStatusMessage",
            button: "IBNSubscribeButton",
            successMsg: "Thank you for signing up!",
            emailValidation: true,
            errorMsg: "Oops...please check your email address"
        };
        var opt = $.extend(defaults, opt);
        $("#"+opt.button).click(function(){
        var valid = true;
        if(opt.emailValidation){
if(!isValidEmailAddress($("#"+opt.email).val()))
{
valid = false;
}
            }
    if(valid){
var data = $("#"+opt.form).serialize();
var img = "";
for (i in lists){
    img += "<img style='display:none;' src='http://server1.emailcampaigns.net/autoadd/?c="+client_id+"&"+data+"&lid="+lists[i]+"'>";
    }
    $("#"+opt.form).html(opt.successMsg + img);
        }else{
        $("#"+opt.msg).html(opt.errorMsg);
        }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.fn.EmailCampaignsSubscribe(a00000a,[3]);</script>
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: I aligned the first line w/ the left margin. If there are other indentation issues, that is the way the code was formatted at the source. I don't have the knowledge to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this anywhere in your document:

```
<style>
    [type="text"], [type="email"]{
        background:#fafafa !important;
        height:3em important; 
        border:1px solid #cccccc important; 
        border-radius:4px important; 
        -moz-border-radius: 4px important;
    }
    [type="text"]:focus, [type="email"]:focus{
        background:#ffffff !important;
        height:3em !important;
        border:1px solid #cccccc !important;
        border-radius:4px !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px !important;
    }
</style>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/Ad3aT/)
In the example the background is red when not focused so you can see the difference.
Change it by replacing `background:red !important;` with `background:white !important;`
You can also make the focus fade in by using this coding:

```
 <style>
            [type="text"], [type="email"]{
                background:#fafafa !important;
                height:3em important; 
                border:1px solid #cccccc important; 
                border-radius:4px important; 
                -moz-border-radius: 4px important;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px
                -o-transition:.5s;
                -ms-transition:.5s;
                -moz-transition:.5s ;
                -webkit-transition:.5s;
                 transition:.5s  ;

            }
            [type="text"]:focus, [type="email"]:focus{
                background:#ffffff !important;
                height:3em !important;
                border:1px solid #cccccc !important;
                border-radius:4px !important;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px !important;
            }
        </style>
```

[Example of fade](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/Ad3aT/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you; I tried pasting the first of the two examples, but I can't get it to work. I know you said anywhere w/in the doc, but does your code need to be within specific HTML tags?

Comment: :focus cannot be inside of a html tag. what is the url of your website? you might have some overriding coding.

Comment: It's a SquareSpace site and not live yet. I'll ask on their user forum what is the best way to add your CSS code.

Comment: Alright, [Follow this tutorial](http://help.squarespace.com/guides/using-the-css-editor#toc-access-the-css-editor). Copy the coding above inside the <style> tags, do not copy the style tags, then paste it at the bottom of your css. If that doesn't work, could you post your website and then i can lead you through it step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
input[type=text] {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

You could do things with javascript too but wanted to keep it simple for you.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3kN8F/1/

Note: I used red here to demonstrate it better for you :)

Comment: Thank you; I'm having trouble getting this to work - given the code I provided, where does the new code go?

Comment: You can put it between the <style>insert my css here</style> tags, anywhere on your page for convinience :)

Comment: Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp . I told you the Internal Style Sheet part. So read that part for more info :).